# Erro ao versionar utilizando Git no Ubuntu

Tags: cakephp, linux, git, versionamento, bitbucket

Então, atualmente estou utilizando o sistema operacional Ubuntu 15.04 para desenvolver minhas atividades diárias. Tenho um projeto web em PHP onde utilizo o Framework CakePHP 3 e versiono meu projeto no BitBucket.

O meu problema é o seguinte, quando eu clono meu projeto direto do BitBucket para ele ficar acessível localmente e rodo o comando `$ sudo composer install` no diretório onde meu projeto se localiza para ele instalar as variáveis de ambiente, meu projeto fica inacessível na web por falta de permissões em alguns diretórios localizados dentro da pasta dele [Erro apresentado pelo CakePHP informando que não é possível acessar alguns arquivos, por falta de permissão]. Ao conceder as permissões de leitura e escrita à pasta do meu projeto e acessa-lo novamente via web, algumas paginas não são redirecionadas corretamente [Erro apresentado pelo CakePHP informando que o Controller "X" não foi encontrado], porem não alterei nada além de permissões.

Ao executar o comando `$ git status` no diretorio do meu projeto percebo que há inúmeras modificações em classes e arquivos de configuração do mesmo, sendo que não alterei nada.

**TESTES REALIZADOS:**

- Clonar projeto, executar o comando `$ git status` => não apresenta modificações.
- Clonar projeto, executar o comando `$ sudo composer install` e logo apos executar o comando `$ git status` => não apresenta modificações.
- Clonar projeto, executar o comando `$ sudo composer install` e logo apos executar o comando `$ git status`, conceder permissões ao diretório do projeto => apresenta inúmeras modificações.
- Clonar projeto, conceder permissões ao diretório do projeto e executar o comando `$ git status` => apresenta inúmeras modificações.

*Como proceder com esta situação?*

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Não clone ou rode o composer install usando sudo. A chance de ocorrer problemas de permissão são um tanto grandes.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o mesmo usuário do dono do diretório.
Usar `sudo composer install` faz com que seja utilizado o root. Use apenas `composer install`.
Se o usuário não conseguir escrever no diretório alvo, tente adicioná-lo ao mesmo grupo do usuário dono com o comando
`usermod -a -G <nome grupo> <nome usuario>`

Ou

Execute todos os comandos usando o usuario root - [Não recomendado]

Comment: Creio muito que o problema não seja o **composer**, pois mesmo executando o comando `composer install` e concedendo permissões root para a pasta do projeto, o problema persiste. Aparece em minha stage inúmeros arquivos, que se quer foram alterados. Ou seja, o problema com o versionamento ocorre apos a concessão de privilégios à pasta do projeto. Não faz muito sentido eu alterar as permissões de uma pasta e o Git interpretar que os arquivos dela sofreram alterações.

Comment: Faz o seguinte teste (eu fiz aqui)

`[user] git status
 nothing to commit (working directory clean)
 [user] echo foo > bar
 [user] git add bar; git commit -m "teste"
 [user] git status
 nothing to commit (working directory clean)
 [user] chmod 777 bar
 [user] git status
 #(...)
#       modified:   bar`

Perceba que ao simplesmente mudar as permissões do arquivo você efetivamente muda o arquivo. As permissões estão _ marcadas_ diretamente no arquivo e portanto alterá-las fará o git acusar mudança.
Use o mesmo usuário para fazer deste o `git init` até a finalização do composer.